# Code First EF - Many-to-Many Relationship Among Properties in An Entity

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a mock social media app, and my goal currently is to keep track of followers and followings for each entity called `ForumProfile`. I created ICollection properties of 'followers' and followings' that consist of entity type `ForumProfileSimplified` (i.e. without followers and followings as to prevent circular references):

```
 public class ForumProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ForumProfileId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 100)]
        public int? Age { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(2000)]
        public string? ProfileURL { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Interest> Interests { get; set; } = new List<Interest>();

        public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();

        public ICollection<ForumProfileSimplified> Followers { get; set; } = new List<ForumProfileSimplified>();

        public ICollection<ForumProfileSimplified> Followings { get; set; } = new List<ForumProfileSimplified>();

    }

 public class ForumProfileSimplified
    {
        [Key]
        // Automatically generates new ID when new profile is added
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ForumProfileSimplifiedId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(2000)]
        public string? ProfileURL { get; set; }
    }
```

In the DbContext, with a little AI help, I attempted to seed the database:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ForumProfile>().HasData(
                new ForumProfile
                {
                    ForumProfileId = 1,
                    DisplayName = "User1",
                    Age = 30,
                    ProfileURL = "https://example.com/user2"
                },
                new ForumProfile
                {
                    ForumProfileId = 2,
                    DisplayName = "User2",
                    Age = 22,
                    ProfileURL = "https://example.com/user2"
                });

modelBuilder.Entity<ForumProfileSimplified>().HasData(
       new ForumProfileSimplified
       {
           ForumProfileSimplifiedId = 1,
           DisplayName = "User1",
           ProfileURL = "https://example.com/user1"
       },
       new ForumProfileSimplified
       {
           ForumProfileSimplifiedId = 2,
           DisplayName = "User2",
           ProfileURL = "https://example.com/user2"
       }
   );

 modelBuilder.Entity<ForumProfile>().HasMany(fp => fp.Followers)
     .WithMany(fp => fp.Followings)
     .UsingEntity(join =>
         {
           join.HasData(
             new { FollowersForumProfileId = 1, FollowingsForumProfileSimplifiedId = 2 },
             new { FollowersForumProfileId = 2, FollowingsForumProfileSimplifiedId = 1 }
             );
           });
```

However, the project won't build - "fp.followings" is of type `ForumProfileSimplified` and does not contain the property `followings`. This makes sense - so how would I reformat this seeding?

Comment: There is a reason social media lead to the rise of graph databases...